# Windows 10 Slow internet VS Linux system but only overseas connections

Tags: windows, networking, performance

I've got mind bending problem. Download speed on Windows 10 machine is way slower than on Linux machine but only on connections from EU to US.

Here are the variables:

- Machine A, Windows 10
- Machine B, Ubuntu 18
- They are connected to the very same network 70 Mbit

Machine A Windows speed test to server in Europe ~66 Mbit/s
Machine B Linux speed test to server in Europe ~66 Mbit/s

**Machine A Windows speed test to server in US 6 Mbit/s**
Machine B Linux speed test to server in US 66 MBit/s

We made sure to repeat the tests several times.
Here is the screenshot of the speed from Windows machine:
[image]

And here is speed test for the Linux machine:
[image]

The thing is, they are connected to the same network so the issue needs to be in the Windows itself. I would understand if the speed was slower in general but only when connecting to US? How is this even possible?

Comment: Intercontinental TCP connections experience higher latency and probably higher packet loss. Both of these can be challenges to your TCP Congestion Control algorithm. I believe modern Linux and Windows 10 both default to using CUBIC as their TCP Congestion Control algorithm, but you might want to look up how to double-check that on your systems. If they're not both using the same congestion control algorithm for these connections, you might want to see if switching algorithms makes a difference.

Comment: If you don't mind nerding out about TCP a little bit, you might also consider getting packet captures of both cases and then using a tool like tcptrace to help you analyze what's going on.